# GA4 on Mobile Apps: retroactively deleting data for anonymous users that set GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_ANALYTICS_STORAGE to FALSE

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, privacy, gdprconsentform

In GA4, for mobile applications users, is it possible to retroactively delete data for users that set the GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_ANALYTICS_STORAGE flag to **false**?

**Swift Code example**:

`Analytics.setConsent([ .analyticsStorage: .granted .adStorage: .granted ])`

**What I have done**:

I checked on the documentation to see if there is an API.

My understanding is that Google has unique anonymous users ID.

Currently, for an app that is tracking anonymously users, I would like to give them the chance to set "no".

What I'd like to try achieve is, when I roll out the app update with the setConsent mode,
for the user sets consent to "No" to retrieve the anonymous UUID and then delete all the previously stored data.

I couldn't find much documentation about this.